# How to silence linux kernel checkpatch.pl ERROR: Missing Signed-off-by: line(s)

Tags: patch

I use the Linux kernel style in my C code, even though it's not related to the kernel. Running `checkpatch.pl` produces `ERROR: Missing Signed-off-by: line(s)`. How to ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To intentionally silence the `ERROR: Missing Signed-off-by: line(s)` one can pass the `--no-signoff` parameter, e.g.:

`git show | checkpatch.pl --no-tree --no-signoff`

This can also be added on a new line to the *.checkpatch.conf* file to avoid having to type it.